# How can I find whether datatables have same no of rows and same filenames in each row

Tags: c#

In my C# application I have three datatables:

#### Datatable1

```
DataView view = wavdt.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Wfname";
DT1 = view.ToTable();
```

#### Datatable2

```
DataView view = basedt.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Bfname";
DT2 = view.ToTable();
```

#### Datatable3

```
DataView view = templatedt.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Tfname";
DT3 = view.ToTable();
```

I need to ensure that all the three datatables contain the same number of rows and the same filenames in all of the three datatables.

How can I do this?

I know that we can write a condition to see `(dt1.rows.count == dt2.rows.count == dt3.rows.count)` for rows count but how can I check for same file names in all the three datatables. My filenames will be same but extensions will be different.

If I have `123.wmv` in datatable1, I will have 123.doc in second datatable and same 123 in third datatable either with doc or docx extension. If I have five rows in 1st datatable I need to ensure that my remaining datatables contain same five rows with same filenames if not then I should show error message and stop execution of my next lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
bool HasSame(DataTable w, DataTable b, DataTable t)
{
    if((w.Rows.Count == b.Rows.Count && b.Rows.Count ==  t.Rows.Count) == false ) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < w.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var field1 = w.Rows[i]["Wfname"].ToString() ;
        var field2 = b.Rows[i]["Bfname"] .ToString() ;
        var field3 = t.Rows[i]["Tfname"].ToString() ;

        //if its equal, uneccary GetFileNameWithoutExtension
        if(field1 == field2 && field2 == field3) continue;

        field1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(field1) ;
        field2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(field2) ;
        field3 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(field3) ;

        if( (field1 == field2 && field2 == field3) == false)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The function assumes that tables are already sorted, which is a bit of a pity. It would be best if sorting was done only if the rows were the same as saving unnecessary action. but for do this you need taking out the DataTable of function parameters to class fields, Thus, placing the sorted table into a variable will not be only in the function variable scope - This is of course if you need the sort even without comparison, if not, I would suggest a more elegant code:

```
bool HasSame(DataTable w, DataTable b, DataTable t)
{
    if((w.Rows.Count == b.Rows.Count && b.Rows.Count ==  t.Rows.Count) == false ) return false;

    var wHashSet = DataTableToHashSet (w, "Wfname");
    var bHashSet = DataTableToHashSet (b, "Bfname");

    if(!wHashSet.SetEquals(bHashSet))
        return false;

    var tHashSet = DataTableToHashSet (t, "Tfname");

    return tHashSet.SetEquals(wHashSet);
}

HashSet<string> DataTableToHashSet(DataTable dt, string fieldName)
{
    return new HashSet<string>(dt.AsEnumerable().Select (dr =>
                                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( dr[fieldName].ToString())
                               ));
}
```